# Matplotlib contour plot of matrix type

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I'm getting hung trying to create a contour plot of three [1, m] numpy matrices. When I try to plot:

```
plt.contour(reg.theta[0,:], reg.theta[1,:], reg.J[0,:])

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I think this has something to do with the fact that

```
In[167]: shape(reg.theta[0,:])

Out[167]: (1, 15000)
```

and contour wants something along the lines of `(15000,)`

I've tried to create a meshgrid similar to how I would in matlab using

```
X , Y = meshgrid(reg.theta[0,:], reg.theta[1,:]

ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged[1,:])
```

However, I have no idea how to interpret this.

Please advise stackoverflow!

Here is my complete code, tested on Python 2.7

```
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
class LinearRegression: 

    def __init__(self, data):

        self.data_loc = data
        self.max_it = 15000
        self.theta = matrix(ones((2, self.max_it)))
        self.alpha = .01
        self.J = matrix(zeros((1, self.max_it)))


    def importData(self):

        Data = loadtxt(self.data_loc, delimiter = ',')
        rawData = matrix(Data)
        x = rawData[:,0]
        y = rawData[:,1]
        [m,n] = shape(x)
        x_0 = matrix(ones((m,1)))
        x = concatenate((x_0, x), axis = 1)

        return x, y, m, n

    def center(self, x):

        x = x / mean(x)

        return x 

    def scale(self, x):

        x = x/ std(x)

        return x 

    def funct(self, m, b):

        return lambda x: m*x + b 


    def cost(self, x, y, m, mx, b):

        f = self.funct(mx, b)
        err = power( (f(x) - y), 2).sum()
        err = err / (2*len(x))

        return err

    def gradientDesc(self, x, y, m):

        for i in range(0, self.max_it -1):

            error = (1.0/m) * transpose(x) * ((x * self.theta[:,i]) - y ) 
            delta = self.theta[:,i] - self.alpha*error

            self.J[0,i] = (self.cost( x, y, m, self.theta[1,i], self.theta[0,i]))

            self.theta[:, i+1] = delta

        print('Calculation Complete')
        return self.theta, error


reg = LinearRegression('/users/michael/documents/machine_learning/ex1/ex1data1.txt')
x, y, m ,n = reg.importData()
theta, error = reg.gradientDesc(x,y,m)
print (reg.theta[:,reg.max_it -1])
XX = linspace(0,m,m)
J = reg.theta[0,reg.max_it-1] + reg.theta[1, reg.max_it-1] * XX 
plt.plot(XX, J)
plt.scatter(x[:,1],y)`
```

Comment: Take a look at http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2012-February/060184.html.

Comment: unfortunately, I am on a mac...

I suppose I am more confused as to why I cannot directly use contour(x,y,z) since all my arguments are 2D vectors (which meshgrid would be used to make)